# Replacing character strings (values) in a column in R with integers in an efficient (vectorized) way

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, vectorization

I have a big dataframe and I want to replace the values in a column which are character strings with integers.  There are more than one thousand unique strings in this column.  One way is through a for loop. Here is the code with a toy dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
library(stringr)
mtcars$gear = as.character(mtcars$gear)
unique_values = unique(mtcars$gear)

for (i in (1:length(unique_values))){

   mtcars$gear =  str_replace(string = mtcars$gear, pattern = unique_values[i], replacement = as.character(i))

}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Do you need `match(mtcars$gear, unique(mtcars$gear))` ?

Comment: `as.integer(factor(mtcars$gear))`? You can use the `labels` within factor to change it the way you want

Comment: The solution to convert to factor using the unique values as levels and integers as labels proved very effective, fast and elegant.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` library should do the trick:

```
data(mtcars)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)


mtcars$gear = as.character(mtcars$gear)

mutate(mtcars, gear = as.integer(gear))
```